# Integrating Play Integrity API in Ionic 5 Cordova app to detect rooted devices

Tags: cordova, ionic5, angular11

I am developing an Ionic 5 app with Cordova and Angular 11, and I am currently using the SafetyNet Google API to detect rooted devices. However, I encountered an issue where the security check was bypassed when users utilized the Magisk Manager app with the deny list option.

After referring to the Google official documentation, I learned that the SafetyNet API is deprecated, and they recommend using the newer Play Integrity API. I would like to know how I can integrate the Play Integrity API into my Ionic 5 Cordova app with Angular 11.

Specifically, I am looking for guidance on the following:

1. Are there any specific permissions or configurations needed within my Ionic app to communicate with the Play Integrity API?
2. Are there any available Cordova plugins or libraries that provide support for the Play Integrity API integration in Ionic?
3. If there are no existing plugins, how can I directly call the Play Integrity API endpoints in my Ionic app?

I have searched extensively for relevant resources and documentation but haven't found any specific examples or tutorials for integrating the Play Integrity API in an Ionic 5 Cordova app with Angular 11.

Any guidance, code examples, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if there are any considerations or best practices I should be aware of while implementing this integration, please let me know.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? have you created any plugins for this?